# EmailMessage Bounce Reason. How to find it from the email, not associated to a Contact/Lead/Person Account?

Tags: email, emailmessage, bounce-management

On a Contact/Lead/Person Account object there is an "EmailBouncedReason" field along with an "IsEmailBounced" field, which makes it possible to understand a cause and fix it.

But on the EmailMessage object, there is only "IsEmailBounced" without the "EmailBouncedReason". When the email is sent, let's say, from an Opportunity to an address, not associated with Contact/Lead/Person Account, I only see an icon in the activity tab and can't understand the reason for the bounce.

Maybe I'm missing something and there is a way to find out the reason in that case?

[image: Activity tab]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there's no field to store the reason on the EmailMessage itself, as you noted, you'd have to [request an Email Log](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.email_logs_edit.htm&type=5) for that date (or filter by email address) for more information.

Another option is to select the `Return bounced emails to sender` in Bounce Management (`Setup --> Deliverability`) which would provide immediate feedback assuming the sender email address is accessible. If this is not selected, the help text mentions the following

> If not selected, salesforce.com displays the bounce alert but discards
> the bounced message.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I'll consider these options.